# Become trusted by Ignacio Rivas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

The Fallout Wiki guide claims that the quest `That Lucky Old Sun` will generate rewards from Rivas if you are "trusted" with him. How does one become that? I have tried multiple ways of directing power and none of them spawn any new dialogue options with him (or "The idiot" for that matter).

Comment: I think you have to select the right dialogue options with him before hand, then go send the power to the places that he says need it (I believe it's Freeside & somewhere else) Then go talk to him, if you've done it right you'll get Followers rep and a Big Book of Science.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting "trusted" status with Rivas requires some [specific dialog choices](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/That_Lucky_Old_Sun) when you first speak to him:

> Rivas will only give the player his [password] if the player **gains his trust** by professing to be peaceful (or at least not trying to get involved - both available if the courier states they only work for themselves), states that they want what he wants (must know Rivas is with the Followers, requiring a speech check or Confirmed Bachelor perk), or if the player claims to be with the Brotherhood of Steel. **This may only be done on the first conversation.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I knew I should have made my comment an answer :P

Comment: You mention that this requires `Confirmed Bachelor`. Does this mean that having `Black Widow` as a female does not work in the same instance?

Comment: @Yawus, he has as particular orientation :)  Both the quest page for Lucky Old Sun and his own page make specific mention of Confirmed Bachelor and no mention of Black Window.